# Error:aes-256-cbc: not found [No such file or directory]

Tags: unix, encryption, openssl, cryptography, ksh

I am running a unix script in which I am pasing a USERNAME and a PASSWORD to isql to connect to sybase databse and I have used the below command to encrypt and decrypt the password which I am passing to isql command but I am getting the below error.

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -in sybase_pwd.txt -out SybasePad.txt.enc -pass file:SybasePadKey.txt
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in SybasePad.txt.enc -pass file:SybasePadKey.txt
```

I am using the above command to encrypt and decrypt but I am getting this error:

```
error:aes-256-cbc: not found [No such file or directory]
```

But when I run the same command in putty it works fine. Could you please assis me?

```
#!/bin/ksh
export SCRIPT_HOME=/tmp/REGCOM

cd ${SCRIPT_HOME}
DBPASSWORDENC=openssl aes-256-cbc -salt -in sybase_pwd.txt -out SybasePad.txt.enc -pass file:SybasePadKey.txt
DBPASSWORD=openssl aes-256-cbc -d -salt -in SybasePad.txt.enc -pass file:SybasePadKey.txt
echo $DBPASSWORDENC
echo $DBPASSWORD
exit
```

Posted sample script but still the same error.

Comment: Can you strip things from the script until you have an full example of a simple failing script that you can post? I think it's likely a syntax error / some trivial typo. The commands as you posted them will work just fine.

Comment: @viraptor..Added sample script which I am trying to execute

Comment: Hi @Azhar Could you post the value of SCRIPT_HOME and the values in the files used in openssl ?

Answer (score 0):

You're running this in `ksh`, not in `bash` as you originally tagged, but the same thing would happen in both. You're running

```
DBPASSWORDENC=openssl aes-256-cbc ....
```

which is actually running command `aes-256-cbc` with environment variable DBPASSWORDENC set to openssl.

You likely want something like:

```
DBPASSWORDENC=$(openssl aes-256-cbc ....)
```